# A simple tree class with smart pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, smart-pointers

I am learning smart pointers. Using smart pointers, I can think of a simple class to implement a binary tree, as shown below.

```
class BinTree
{
  ....
  std::unique_ptr<BinTree> leftChild;
  std::unique_ptr<BinTree> rightChild;
};
```

Things get complicated though, If I also want to keep a pointer to the parent, because in that case each node will be pointed from 3 nodes (2 children and one parent). One could use `shared_ptr` of course, but I've read that it is too inefficient. So, what would be the best solution here?

I was thinking of using a `weak_ptr` to point the parent because children would not be creating/owning their parents anyway, but a `weak_ptr` cannot be created from a `unique_ptr`, only a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: A regular, naked, dumb pointer. The children don't own the parent, and by construction the children won't outlive the parents, so the pointer will remain valid for the lifetime of the child.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.

Comment: Take care of the edge-case when the tree is unbalanced.  The cascade delete from the root (when you finally delete the root node) can cause stack overflow.

Comment: deletes can cause stackoverflow? Can you elaborate this a bit more?

Comment: @pythonic: Imagine you have a very tall tree. When you destroy the root, in the destructor call stack it calls a child's destructor. That child destructor's call stack then calls *its* child's destructor, and so on. You get a bunch of nested calls to the destructors, until finally one child is null and the recursion stops. Herb Sutter touches on this and various work-arounds here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE

Comment: or implement a postorder iterator.